# In App Delegate call method from another class

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, uiapplicationdelegate

I have a view which contains scroll view with some subviews (UIViewControllers). I want to call a method (stop timer) from a class, one of their UIViewControllers, in applicationWillResignActive: method of App Delegate.

What's the best way to implement this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't worry about handling that event in your app delegate and passing it on. Just register for a notification in whatever class you're interested in handling the event from:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(someMethod:)
                                             name:UIApplicationWillResignActiveNotification
                                           object:nil];
```

Comment: Thanks. Never known about this kind of notifications :)